# How to get a list of all the legal moves in the python-chess module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-chess

I am using the python chess module. On the website, it shows that you can check if a move is legal by using

```
import chess

board = chess.Board()
move = input("Enter a chess move: ")
if move in board.legal_moves:
    # Some code to do if the move is a legal move
```

However, I want to be able to get a move from `board.legal_moves`. When I try this:

```
print(board.legal_moves[0])
```

This returns the following error:

```
TypeError: 'LegalMoveGenerator' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I select a move as if I were using a list? Then, how would I use the selection as a move?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generate a list from the generator.

```
legal_moves = list(board.legal_moves)
```

Legal moves is now a list.

```
print(legal_moves)

[Move.from_uci('g1h3'), Move.from_uci('g1f3'), Move.from_uci('b1c3'),
 Move.from_uci('b1a3'), Move.from_uci('h2h3'), Move.from_uci('g2g3'), 
 Move.from_uci('f2f3'), Move.from_uci('e2e3'), Move.from_uci('d2d3'), 
 Move.from_uci('c2c3'), Move.from_uci('b2b3'), Move.from_uci('a2a3'), 
 Move.from_uci('h2h4'), Move.from_uci('g2g4'), Move.from_uci('f2f4'), 
 Move.from_uci('e2e4'), Move.from_uci('d2d4'), Move.from_uci('c2c4'), 
 Move.from_uci('b2b4'), Move.from_uci('a2a4')]
```

Answer (score 10):

The `board.legal_moves` object is a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), or more specifically a `LegalMoveGenerator`. You can iterate over that object and it will yield something with each iteration. You can convert it to a list with `list(board.legal_moves)` and then index it as normal.

```
import chess
board = chess.Board()
legal_moves = list(board.legal_moves)
legal_moves[0]  # Move.from_uci('g1h3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use editing and eval function:

```
import chess # Import chess

board = chess.Board() # Create chess board

moves_t = str(board.legal_moves)[37:-1] # Get the tuple as string
moves_t = moves_t.replace(", ", "', '") # Converting all the SAN names into strings
moves_t = moves_t.replace("(", "('")
moves_t = moves_t.replace(")", "')")
moves_t = eval(moves_t) # Using eval function to turn into tuple
moves = [] # Creates list to store values
for i in moves_t: # Go through all values
    moves.append(i) # Add them to empty list
```

Though this may be bad, it is possible.

Comment: Eval is bad practice. At the least, you should use ast.literal_eval

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output as a simple list:

```
legal_moves_lst = [
    board.san(move)
    for move in board.legal_moves
]
print(legal_moves_lst)
```

Output:

```
['Nh3', 'Nf3', 'Nc3', 'Na3', 'h3', 'g3', 'f3', 'e3', 'd3', 'c3', 'b3', 'a3', 'h4', 'g4', 'f4', 'e4', 'd4', 'c4', 'b4', 'a4']
```